# Publishing/subscribing multiple field selection of the same collection

Tags: collections, meteor, publish-subscribe

i have a post collection that contains an embedded array of comments.
in each post view page, i need to publish 2 cursors: one witch contains all posts without their comments field (performance) to show in some widget, and another witch contains the selected post with it's comments. server side code looks like:

```
Meteor.publish('allPosts', function() {
  return Posts.find({}, {fields: {'comments':0}})
})
Meteor.publish('singlePost', function(slug) {
  return Posts.find({slug: slug})
})
```

in post view template, i subscribe for both of these, but when i use

```
Posts.findOne({slug: slug})
```

how can i know witch publication cursor is used? how can i choose one?

Answer (score 2):

When you query `Posts` on the client, you are querying the union of all active subscriptions on that collection. In this case, if you have subscribed to `singlePost` with that particular `slug`, you will get the full document. If you have not, you will not get the comments.

Another example:

```js
Meteor.publish("allSummaries", function () {
  return Posts.find({}, {fields: {title: 1, date: 1}});
});
Meteor.publish("myPosts", function () {
  return Posts.find({creator: this.userId}, {fields: {title: 1, rating: 1}});
});
Meteor.publish("singlePost", function (_id) {
  return Posts.find({_id: _id}, {fields: {title: 1, body: 1});
});
```

Suppose a client with userId "me" is subscribed to `allSummaries`, `myPosts` and `singlePost` (with `_id` of "3"). The collection contains these documents:

```js
{_id: "1", title: "Post 1", date: "yesterday", creator: "someone else", rating: 3}
{_id: "2", title: "Post 2", date: "today", creator: "me", rating: 4}
{_id: "3", title: "Post 3", date: "5 days ago", creator: "someone else", rating: 2}
```

For Post 1, the client will only see `title` and `date` (and `_id`) - published from `allSummaries` - but nothing else. For post 2, they will see `title`, `date`, and `rating` - the `date` comes from `allSummaries`, the `title` from both `allSummaries` and `myPosts`, and `rating` from `myPosts`. For post 3, they will see `title`, `date` and `body`, but not `rating`.

Comment: "union of all active subscriptions", thats it!
but not mentioned in the docs anywhere

Comment: Much more clearly put than I've been able to find elsewhere. Upvote!